# Android Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x8 in tid 25951

Tags: java, android

I am receiving the following error and it causing application crash, 
I am using imageview with Universal Image loader and with next button to load next image after some images loading with the help of button event error appears. 
I clear the cache and clean the project in android studio, The code seams good to me, There I spend a week but with no luck, Please gurus help me to resolve the issue.

```
    08-28 20:52:54.981 26751-26751/? A/google-breakpad: -----BEGIN BREAKPAD MICRODUMP-----
    08-28 20:52:54.981 26751-26751/? A/google-breakpad: V WebView:48.0.2564.106
    08-28 20:52:54.981 26751-26751/? A/google-breakpad: O A arm64 08 aarch64 samsung/noblelteub/noblelte:6.0.1/MMB29K/N920TUVU4DPK6:user/release-keys
    08-28 20:52:54.981 26751-26751/? A/google-breakpad: G OpenGL ES 3.1 v1.r7p0-03rel0.b596bd02e7d0169c10574b57180c8b57|ARM|Mali-T760
    08-28 20:52:54.981 26751-26751/? A/google-breakpad: S 0 0000007FDBC39720 0000007FDBC39000 0000000000006000
    08-28 20:52:54.991 26751-26751/? A/google-breakpad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
    08-28 20:52:54.991 26751-26751/? A/google-breakpad: S 0000007FDBC39180 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
    08-28 20:52:54.991 26751-26751/? A/google-breakpad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
    08-28 20:52:54.991 26751-26751/? A/google-breakpad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
    08-28 20:52:54.991 26751-26751/? A/google-breakpad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
    08-28 20:52:54.991 26751-26751/? A/google-breakpad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
    08-28 20:52:54.991 26751-26751/? A/google-breakpad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
    08-28 20:52:54.991 26751-26751/? A/google-breakpad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
    08-28 20:52:54.991 26751-26751/? A/google-breakpad: S 0000007FDBC39C00 74419B6E7F0000000000F61200000000B89FC3DB7F000000D8D69D6E7F000000030000007F00000030A3C3DB7F0000005868D16F00000000000000000000000000B8631330715C130000000000B8631330715C137F0000003C1B75827F000000109DC3DB7F0000008099D41202000000809DC3DB7F000000A07277827F000000930000000000000030A3C3DB7F000000004ABB827F0000009A829B6E7F00000000E00A1300000000F89FC3DB7F0000006F200000000000000100080000000000080000000000000084A1C3DB7F000000C8A6C3DB7F000000D8D69D6E7F00000010DDC3DB7F0000006E1000000000000000A0AF827F000000004ABB827F00000002000000000000000300000000000000020000007F00000040A3C3DB7F000000E0B5E16C7F0000001E000000000000000000000000000000000000007F0000003E00000000000000E4419B6E7F000000609EC3DB7F0000004C965A827F00000040A3C3DB7F00000094C8996E7F00000000000000000000000CA619AD1A4156E7
    08-28 20:52:54.991 26751-26751/? A/google-breakpad: S 0000007FDBC39D80 509EC3DB7F000000E0975A827F00000030A3C3DB7F0000009A829B6E7F00000001000000000000006F2000000000000000A0AF827F000000004ABB827F00000040C2AE827F00000000C0AE827F00000088829B6E7F00000098829B6E7F00000000B86313000000001D0200000000000000A0AF827F000000004ABB827F00000040C2AE827F00000000C0AE827F00000088829B6E7F00000084A1C3DB7F00000000A0AF827F000000004ABB827F00000028D7C3DB7F0000000100000000B86313004ABB827F0000000100000000000000B0A2C3DB7F0000002C1B75827F00000030A3C3DB7F00000098E3AF827F000000984ABB827F000000004ABB827F00000038A6C3DB7F000000000000000000000088829B6E7F00000070A9C3DB7F00000000A0AF827F0000003CA3C3DB7F000000C8A6C3DB7F000000D8D69D6E7F00000010DDC3DB7F00000038A6C3DB7F000000B832F057550000003CA1000000000000E0A7C3DB7F00000008A8C3DB7F000000E0A7C3DB7F00000008A8C3DB7F000000
    08-28 20:52:55.001 26751-26751/? A/google-breakpad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
    08-28 20:52:55.001 26751-26751/? A/google-breakpad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
    08-28 20:52:55.001 26751-26751/? A/google-breakpad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
    08-28 20:52:55.001 26751-26751/? A/google-breakpad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
    08-28 20:52:55.001 26751-26751/? A/google-breakpad: S 0000007FDBC3A500 10DDC3DB7F00000058ADC3DB7F000000B832F05755000000A8E0C3DB7F00000000AFC3DB7F00000028AFC3DB7F00000010DDC3DB7F00000058ADC3DB7F000000B832F05755000000A8E0C3DB7F00000000AFC3DB7F00000028AFC3DB7F00000080A5C3DB7F000000B4A8C3DB7F0000007CA7C3DB7F0000008CA8C3DB7F0000005CA7C3DB7F00000064A8C3DB7F0000003CA7C3DB7F0000003CA8C3DB7F0000001CA7C3DB7F000000FCA6C3DB7F00000014A8C3DB7F000000ECA7C3DB7F000000C4A7C3DB7F0000009CA7C3DB7F0000004CA7C3DB7F0000002CA7C3DB7F00000070A7C3DB7F00000050A7C3DB7F00000030A7C3DB7F00000010A7C3DB7F000000F0A6C3DB7F00000058A8C3DB7F00000030A8C3DB7F000000A8A8C3DB7F00000080A8C3DB7F000000B8A7C3DB7F00000090A7C3DB7F000000000000000000000060A8C3DB7F000000D8A8C3DB7F000000B0A8C3DB7F000000E8A7C3DB7F000000C0A7C3DB7F000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    08-28 20:52:55.001 26751-26751/? A/google-breakpad: S 0000007FDBC3A680 A0A7C3DB7F00000020ED71867F000000789DA3407F000000200000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000403BDA6C7F00000070C1B83D7F000000000000000000000000B8631300000000E0A6C3DB7F0000007499B4867F00000000A7C3DB7F0000008CE8B4867F000000509DA3407F00000001000000000000000000000000000000F8EAB4867F0000000000000000000000509DA3407F0000000100000000000000000000000000000040A7C3DB7F0000007499B4867F00000060A7C3DB7F0000008CE8B4867F000000E0A7C3DB7F000000F08E5E827F0000000700000000000000D48E5E827F000000004ABB827F0000000100000000000000403BDA6C7F00000070C1B83D7F0000000000000000000000540000000000000000050000000000000301000000000000E0A7C3DB7F000000C831DB847F00000008A8C3DB7F000000006BE24200000000000057007F000000010000000000000000000000000000008CB60D730000000050B807130000000080719C867F000000
    08-28 20:52:55.001 26751-26751/? A/google-breakpad: S 0000007FDBC3A800 50B8071300000000004ABB827F0000003014D06F0000000028D7C3DB7F0000000100000048DC956F070000000000803F6C54D36E7F000000546E9B6E7F00000010DDC3DB7F00000048B2C3DB7F0000000000803F00000000A8E0C3DB7F000000F0B3C3DB7F00000018B4C3DB7F00000050B807130000000040F621130000000070C1B83D7F0000000100000000000000403BDA6C7F00000070C1B83D7F00000000000000000000005400000000000000F0A8C3DB7F0000003C1B75827F00000070A9C3DB7F0000000C0780740000000010A9C3DB7F0000003C1B75820200000020A9C3DB7F0000000CA619AD1A4156E7C0A9C3DB7F000000383D77827F00000070A9C3DB7F000000004ABB827F00000000A0AF827F000000000000000000000048699B6E7F00000058ADC3DB7F00000030589B6E7F00000090B0C3DB7F00000000A0AF827F000000000000000000000034559B6E7F00000058ADC3DB7F000000D8579B6E7F00000090B0C3DB7F000000030000007F00000090B0C3DB7F000000
    08-28 20:52:55.001 26751-26751/? A/google-breakpad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
    08-28 20:52:55.001 26751-26751/? A/google-breakpad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
    08-28 20:52:55.041 26751-26751/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007F86B36000 0000000000000000 0000000000037000 E1F429DC4C6416720FCA0014E33C1C130 libutils.so
    08-28 20:52:55.041 26751-26751/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007F86B6D000 0000000000000000 0000000000028000 AAE9BF2FBE692200EBE41E08D899CDA10 libcutils.so
    08-28 20:52:55.041 26751-26751/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007F86B97000 0000000000000000 0000000000012000 821E3CAC7AC3036FE203A083CA2C32680 libsigchain.so
    08-28 20:52:55.041 26751-26751/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007F86BC9000 0000000000000000 0000000000031000 D9CCFF31ECD7A610CA727B1E38532D0D0 linker64
    08-28 20:52:55.041 26751-26751/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007F86C08000 0000000000000000 0000000000002000 672B2CD6CF8AF6C45BD70F2AB02B3D0C0 linux-gate.so
    08-28 20:52:55.041 26751-26751/? A/google-breakpad: -----END BREAKPAD MICRODUMP-----
```

And there debug begin

```
08-28 20:52:55.071 25951-25951/com.mobilepricess.novelscollectionurdu A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x8 in tid 25951 (scollectionurdu)
08-28 20:52:55.141 3158-3158/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
08-28 20:52:55.141 3158-3158/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'samsung/noblelteub/noblelte:6.0.1/MMB29K/N920TUVU4DPK6:user/release-keys'
08-28 20:52:55.141 3158-3158/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '9'
08-28 20:52:55.151 3158-3158/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
08-28 20:52:55.151 3158-3158/? A/DEBUG: pid: 25951, tid: 25951, name: scollectionurdu  >>> com.mobilepricess.novelscollectionurdu <<<
08-28 20:52:55.151 3158-3158/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x8
08-28 20:52:55.231 3158-3158/? A/DEBUG:     x0   0000000000000000  x1   0000007f82d7d180  x2   0000007fdbc397a4  x3   0000007fdbc397a4
08-28 20:52:55.231 3158-3158/? A/DEBUG:     x4   0000007f82d7d180  x5   0000000000000000  x6   0000007f82afa000  x7   0000007f82afc9a0
08-28 20:52:55.241 3158-3158/? A/DEBUG:     x8   0000007fdbc39780  x9   0000007f82bb4bb0  x10  0000000000000000  x11  0000000000000000
08-28 20:52:55.241 3158-3158/? A/DEBUG:     x12  0000000000000001  x13  0000000000000000  x14  0000007f82b1a68c  x15  0000000000000000
08-28 20:52:55.241 3158-3158/? A/DEBUG:     x16  0000007f82b1a688  x17  0000000000000000  x18  0000007f82bb4a00  x19  0000007fdbc39780
08-28 20:52:55.241 3158-3158/? A/DEBUG:     x20  0000007fdbc39750  x21  0000007f82d7d180  x22  0000000013645e40  x23  0000000000000000
08-28 20:52:55.241 3158-3158/? A/DEBUG:     x24  0000007fdbc39ff8  x25  0000007fdbc39c40  x26  0000007fdbc3a330  x27  0000007f82afa000
08-28 20:52:55.241 3158-3158/? A/DEBUG:     x28  0000007fdbc39c28  x29  0000007fdbc39720  x30  0000007f70fa3780
08-28 20:52:55.241 3158-3158/? A/DEBUG:     sp   0000007fdbc39720  pc   0000007f70fa2bb0  pstate 0000000060000000
08-28 20:52:55.241 3158-3158/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
08-28 20:52:55.241 3158-3158/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00000000010babb0  /system/app/WebViewGoogle/WebViewGoogle.apk (offset 0x279e000)
08-28 20:52:55.241 3158-3158/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 00000000010bb77c  /system/app/WebViewGoogle/WebViewGoogle.apk (offset 0x279e000)
08-28 20:52:56.021 3158-3158/? A/DEBUG: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_02
08-28 20:52:56.021 3158-3158/? E/DEBUG: AM write failed: Broken pipe
08-28 20:52:56.031 4961-4961/? E/audit: type=1701 msg=audit(1567007576.031:2738): auid=4294967295 uid=10256 gid=10256 ses=4294967295 subj=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 pid=25951 comm="scollectionurdu" reason="memory violation" sig=11
08-28 20:52:56.131 3164-3824/? E/OMXNodeInstance: !!! Observer died. Quickly, do something, ... anything...
08-28 20:52:56.131 3164-4418/? E/OMXNodeInstance: !!! Observer died. Quickly, do something, ... anything...
08-28 20:52:56.131 3556-4101/? E/ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ id=673, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN] ]
08-28 20:52:56.181 26767-26767/? E/Zygote: v2
08-28 20:52:56.191 26767-26767/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
08-28 20:52:56.301 26780-26780/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.mobilepricess.novelscollectionurdu-2@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
08-28 20:52:56.851 26785-26785/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.mobilepricess.novelscollectionurdu-2@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
08-28 20:52:56.891 26790-26790/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.mobilepricess.novelscollectionurdu-2@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
08-28 20:52:56.931 26795-26795/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.mobilepricess.novelscollectionurdu-2@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
08-28 20:52:56.981 26800-26800/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.mobilepricess.novelscollectionurdu-2@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
08-28 20:52:57.031 26805-26805/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.mobilepricess.novelscollectionurdu-2@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
08-28 20:52:57.081 26810-26810/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.mobilepricess.novelscollectionurdu-2@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
08-28 20:52:57.121 26815-26815/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.mobilepricess.novelscollectionurdu-2@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
08-28 20:52:57.161 26820-26820/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.mobilepricess.novelscollectionurdu-2@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
08-28 20:52:57.201 26825-26825/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.mobilepricess.novelscollectionurdu-2@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
08-28 20:52:57.271 26829-26829/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.mobilepricess.novelscollectionurdu-2@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
08-28 20:52:58.021 26767-26767/com.mobilepricess.novelscollectionurdu E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = android.hardware.scontext.ISContextService$Stub$Proxy@7827bb9
08-28 20:52:58.021 26767-26767/com.mobilepricess.novelscollectionurdu E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@e573bfe
08-28 20:52:58.021 26767-26767/com.mobilepricess.novelscollectionurdu E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@e573bfe
08-28 20:52:58.361 3556-4387/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 5836 [08-28 20:52:58.366]
08-28 20:52:58.541 26767-26950/com.mobilepricess.novelscollectionurdu E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
08-28 20:52:58.581 26767-26767/com.mobilepricess.novelscollectionurdu E/libEGL: call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
```

Comment: Have you tried adding     `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` to your manifest?

Comment: Yes, Permission already added and it works also, but error is still here, I think its something else.

Comment: Try to add similar permissions related to network such as `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />` and see if anything changes, this most likely is a permission issue.

Comment: There are Permissions brother 'code'<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />'code'

Comment: @AmbreenKhan, have you found a solution for this?